# Como fazer o plano de fundo dentro de uma div ocupar todo o body

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quero colocar uma imagem dentro de uma div que ocupe todo um body, que quando voce aumente a tela com o scroll do mouse, ela continue seguindo o tamanho de toda a tela.
Exemplo de site com plano de fundo assim:
http://www.tecmundo.com.br/
Quando você aumenta a tela com o scroll do mouse, o plano de fundo azul segue o tamanho da tela. Creio eu que esteja dentro da mesma div, com o tamanho exato, mas siga o body com o width.
Já tentei fazer dentro da div:
width:max-body;

width: 1000%; ( Foi a pior de todas, tinha que colocar todos os dados para a esquerda e de acordo com o rolo da tela com o mouse, uma hora nao dava.)

Quem puder ajudar, obrigado. Dúvida simples, porém, é importante, pois posso acessar o algo do body dentro da div e etc.
Se puder fazer com javascript, serve também. HTML, CSS ou Javascript. Obrigado

```
                    <style>
            body {
                margin: auto;
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;
               }              
                    div#cabecario {
                min-height:1780px;
                width: 1000px;
                position:relative;
              }

                 div#fundo {
                background-color:#C0C0C0;
                text-align: center;
                background-image: url("../imagem/logo1.jpg");
                background-size: 100%100%;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                height: 15%;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: black;
                position: absolute;
                top:3%;
            }
</style>


<html>
     <body> 
            //Aqui não tem nada
    <div id="cabecario">
            //Aqui também não tem nada
    <div id="fundo">
           //Aqui é somente para deixar a imagem no início do cabeçário, que começa no top 0%.
             </div>
                 // Aqui vem as outras informações, como aside, p, textos, imagens, etc
               </div>
             //Aqui fecha o cabeçário
                   </body>
                    //Fechou o body
                      </html>
```

Atualmente, meu código está assim. Usei alguns códigos que responderam abaixo, mas não arrumou. Obrigado a quem ajudar

Comment: De qual parte vc ta falando? Seria melhor [edit] a pergunta e por um exemplo do que tentou fazer e o que não está dando certo, fica mais fácil de entendermos. Se for só o cabeçalho, é só por um width:100% na div. E se não funcionar, é por ter alguma coisa errada no aninhamento do CSS, e não com a DIV em si. Não se esqueça de zerar a margem e o padding do body/html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não entendi ainda qual a dificuldade, mas segue um exemplo bem simples que já mostra um [cabeçalho](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=cabe%E7alho) com largura total e um fundo com imagem totalmente preenchida, não importa o tamanho da página:

```css
body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

#cabecalho {
  width:100%;
  height:120px;
  background:#06c;
  color:#fff;
}

#fundo {
  height:80px;
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/800/400) no-repeat center;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body> 
    <div id="cabecalho">
      <div id="fundo">
      </div>
      Aqui vem as outras informações, como aside, p, textos, imagens, etc
    </div>
    Aqui fecha o cabecalho (na verdade no cabeçalho nao era pra ir nem texto, nem aside etc, senão, não é um cabeçalho né? no máximo uns controles pequenos e navegação)
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: " Aqui fecha o cabecalho (na verdade no cabeçalho nao era pra ir nem texto, nem aside etc, senão, não é um cabeçalho né? no máximo uns controles pequenos e navegação)
 "
Foi aqui meu erro inteiro, eu estava fazendo o site dentro de um cabeçalho. Não importava o quanto eu aumentava o zoom da tela, ele ficava no tamanho fixo dele. É mais porque eu aprendi a fazer site pela internet, no caso, se um fizesse o site inteiro dentro do cabeçalho, eu segui e estou aqui até hoje fazendo o mesmo. Obrigado, só essa frase me salvou. Bobo, mas salvou . Obrigado, haha

Answer (score 2):

Se voc^estiver usando alguma div com idéia de container com tamanho de 970px por exemplo, ou qualquer outro valor para dar a largura do site e centralizá-lo, você deve criar uma div com `width="100%"` dentro dessa div vc colocar uma outra com uma width especifica para centralizar o site no meio.

**Por exemplo:**

```
<div style="background-color: red; width:100%;">
   <div style="width:970px; margin: auto;">
      {AQUI VOCÊ INSERE O CONTEUDO DESEJADO}
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: E como o Bacco falou, zere o margin e o padding do seu body! Pois se não ficaram bordar brancas em todo o site!

Comment: Editei a pergunta, se tiver como dar uma ajudinha, bgd

Answer (score 2):

A idéia é fixar o background no body e centraliza-lo, onde o mesmo não será redimensionando quando der zoom.

Ficaria assim:

```
body {
  background: url('https://algumaimagem.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  margin: 0 0 100px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta, se tiver como dar uma ajudinha, grato.